# What service do i need for hosting django (backend) + postgresql (database) on GCP

Tags: django, postgresql, flutter, google-cloud-platform

I want to know what service in Google cloud Platform that i need to deploy my backend django + postgresql? I'm developing a mobile app using flutter.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to host a Django app with PostgreSQL on GCP. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/django) covers the following available options:

- App Engine standard environment
- App Engine flexible Environment
- Cloud Run
- Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE)
- Compute Engine

For the [PostgreSQL database](https://cloud.google.com/python/django#databases), you can use the Cloud SQL.

If you need a Django package that already includes PostgreSQL, you can use the [Django in Google Cloud Marketplace](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/solution/bitnami-launchpad/djangostack?q=django) and deploy your app on the Compute Engine.

Comment: for a small business, which one you suggest ?

Comment: @rvng hard to tell what's the best option but I think a good answer was provided in this [older thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48068940/most-cost-effective-way-to-deploy-to-google-cloud-platform) that covers pricing, reliability, scalability, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud's Flexible **App Engine** Service can definitely work in this case .

**About App Engine**

Google App Engine lets app developers build scalable web and mobile back ends in any programming language on a fully managed serverless platform.

For more detail please check the below link, on how you can achieve the same
https://codeburst.io/beginners-guide-to-deploying-a-django-postgresql-project-on-google-cloud-s-flexible-app-engine-e3357b601b91

Comment: so instead of using google cloud compute , we use cloud flexible app engine for the web service right ? and the database we still need to use google cloud sql.

i thought there is a service like all in one package, for example if u host a web app the vendor alredy have a package that include storage, database management (example phpmyadmin), and cpanel to manage it.

Comment: @rvng there could be options as mentioned by Farid , but I would say seems feasible option to me .